# Script to check if a new file is added to folder or not on Mac OS

Tags: python, typescript

I'm working on Mac, looking for a script that continues running/checking if a file with .csv extension is added to a certain folder or not, if it's added then trigger a the python code mycode.py ?

I've created a python code that can do this but it still needs to press the run button to start, I want to add script instead that once my machine is online start working automatically.. an example also would be helpfull.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your python script through a Cron Job scheduled every minute. These will automatically start running when your computer is turned on. You can even run it every X minutes or X hours if every minute is too often to check.

```
* * * * * python /path/to/script.py
```

See [here](https://linuxhint.com/run_cron_job_every_minute/) for details.